# A linear motion of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bijective mapping of the form $T_A:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T_A(x)=A\underline{x}$

Tags: group-theory

I was reading about group theory. There was a problem given in a book as follows:

> A linear motion of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a bijective mapping of the form $T_A:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T_A(x)=A\underline{x}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ where $A\underline{x}$   is given by the left multiplicaton of the matrix $A$ with the column matrix $\underline {x}$. Show that the set of linear motions is a group under composition of mapping.

However, I am not getting what do they mean by $\underline {x}\in \mathbb {R}^2$? Does they mean ordered pairs $(a,b)$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and then $\underline {x}=\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}$, i.e a column matrix? Also,  what do they mean by "composition of mapping"? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: you have the correct interpretation of $\underline{x}$ denoting a $2\times 1$ matrix and $x$ denoting an ordered pair in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: by "under composition of mapping" the author means that the composition law on the set of linear motions is meant to be function composition

Comment: @CSquared Can you please explain what do u mean by "group composition law"?...

Comment: For example, the integers with addition $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ is a group whose composition law (or group operation) is addition. The symmetric group $(S_n,\circ)$ is a group whose composition law (or group operation) is function composition.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @CSquared So is the value of  $(T_A\circ T_B)(x)$ be equal to $AB\underline {x}$ ? Is the identity element $I\underline {x}$(, where $I$ is an identity matrix) ? Also, inverse exists for  each matrix $A$ if $det(A)\neq 0$ but  we are concerned about the inverse function here ....so What will it be? I am not quite getting it...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here you should think of $x \in \mathbf{R}^2$ as a $2\times 1$ vector. The set you want to show is a group is $\{T_A : A \in \mathsf{GL}_2(\mathbf{R})\}$ and the binary operation is composition of functions. What is $(T_A \circ T_B)(x)$? What is the identity element?

Comment: Well, $(T_A\circ T_B)(x)$ is equal to  $AB\underline {x}$, right? Also , associativity is satisfied here in the group. And if $T_A(x)=I\underline {x}$ (where $I$ is a $2×2$ identity matrix) then  $T_A$ is the identity element , right? Also, what about the inverse of each element?...

Comment: I think that your confusion might be about $\mathsf{GL}_2(\mathbf{R})$. This is the set (group) of $2\times 2$ invertible matrices with coefficients in the real numbers. So since every matrix $A$ has an inverse, this gives you the inverse transformation.

Comment: Well,I do know about $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ but is the value of $(T_A\circ T_B)(x)$ be equal to $AB\underline {x}$ ? Is the identity element $I\underline {x}$(, where $I$ is an identity matrix) ? Also, inverse exists for  each matrix $A$ if $det(A)\neq 0$ but  we are concerned about the inverse function here ....so What will it be? I am not quite getting it...